# How to create a Network Port during run time?

Tags: anylogic

Is it possible to create a Network Port during run time (similar to creating Nodes and Paths, etc)? If so, what is the code/syntax?

Assuming I already have a path called 'path1', I tried the following:

```
NetworkPort nwp1 = new NetworkPort( this, SHAPE_DRAW_2D3D, true, new PathEnd(path1, PathEndType.END) );
```

But it gives and the following error:

```
Description: Cannot instantiate the type NetworkPort.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is not possible. There is an API function [`createPort()`](https://anylogic.help/api/com/anylogic/engine/markup/Network.html#createport) but it is deprecated.

However, you may (!) be able to "agentify" your port: create an agent type with a port in it and instantiate it as needed dynamically.